# Update from CRA4 to CRA5 breaks imports

Tags: reactjs, import, sass, uikit, react-scripts

We used to have react-scripts@4.0.3 and I am trying to update on react-scripts@5.0.1. Unfortunately after going into polyfill problem (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756) and hopefully solving it by aliases I ran into another problem with SCSS files...

Application runs without any problem, everything works fine, but after the compilation I get webpack warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/scss/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/scss/index.scss)Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module. All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths.
    Invalid dependencies may lead to broken watching and caching.
    As best effort we try to convert all invalid values to absolute paths and converting globs into context dependencies, but this is deprecated behavior.
    Loaders: Pass absolute paths to this.addDependency (existing files), this.addMissingDependency (not existing files), and this.addContextDependency (directories).
    Plugins: Pass absolute paths to fileDependencies (existing files), missingDependencies (not existing files), and contextDependencies (directories).
    Globs: They are not supported. Pass absolute path to the directory as context dependencies.
    The following invalid values have been reported:
     * "node_modules:src:src/scss/uikit/src/scss/_mixins-theme"
     * "node_modules:src:src/scss/uikit/src/scss/_mixins-theme.css"
     * "node_modules:src:src/scss/uikit/src/scss/_mixins-theme.import"
     * and more ...
```

I am not able to get rid of this warning. I tried following imports:

```
@import 'uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme';
@import '~uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme';
@import 'uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme.scss';
@import '~uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme.scss';
```

If I import it with .scss, it just change the invalid values to:

```
 * "node_modules:src:src/scss/uikit/src/scss/_mixins-theme.import.scss"
 * "node_modules:src:src/scss/uikit/src/scss/_mixins-theme.import.scss.css"
 * "node_modules:src:src/scss/uikit/src/scss/_mixins-theme.import.scss.sass"
```

I have this problem with multiple files and I have no clue if I solved the relative paths (I basically added absolute ones everywhere) and that error message is changing, but because of I do not see full error log I have no clue if these errors are just "moving" to lower position and I get the top 3 of them or if it is solved. But this one is weird as I do not have any other option how to write the import.

This mixins-theme are imported in imported scss of imported scss of imported scss which is inside the index.scss (so there is multiple nested imports)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we have found the problem, according to:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12329

This what is written in the CRA tutorial seems to be not working:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

We had to **remove the **SASS_PATH** completely** to get rid of the warnings